# SQL Server trigger insert (to update inserted row)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, database-trigger

I need to update a column `U_DIGIT` after inserting a new record (update in this new record) in SQL Server. I think the best way is to use a trigger to do this in the inserted records, but it should by done only in the new records having 'OL' in the `ORIGIN` column.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. Need some help, please. Thanks.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ol_ins_digit 
ON ol
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE ol
    SET u_digit = 'path\' + cast(OL.OLID as varchar(8)) + '.PDF'
    WHERE olstamp IN (SELECT olstamp 
                      FROM inserted 
                      WHERE origin = 'OL')
END
GO
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Any error message? Or unexpected behavior?

Comment: I simulated the insert of my ERP in SQL and got a primary key violation error, but in another table (BA). I believe that when inserting a new record in the OL is also inserted in the BA - when this trigger tries to do the update, as far as I know, delete and reinsert the record, so it triggers a new record in BA giving error because it already has the previous record. To mention if I make a simple update with the trigger query (indicating a specific `olstamp`) everything works perfectly ...

Comment: If you have multiple triggers (Your comment is a bit confusing.) you may need to explicitly set the firing order using [`sp_settriggerorder `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get things to behave as desired. Aside: Does the `u_digit` column also need to be updated when an `update` statement alters the `OLID` value?

Comment: I don't need to `UPDATE` the `u_digit`column. I defined the order of my trigger as the first one with the same result...

Comment: Basically I needed to understand the behavior, because if I run the sql expression to make the `UPDATE` to the `u_digit` column, works perfectly but if I put the expression in a trigger it results in error... is a bit confusing to me and I probably will not be able to expose the problem in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I think Backslash is the problem here. You need to escape that.

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ol_ins_digit 
ON  ol
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  update ol
  set u_digit = 'path\\' + cast(OL.OLID as varchar(8)) + '.PDF'
  where olstamp in (select olstamp from inserted where origin = 'OL')

END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Jain, but I believe this is not the problem. Please see my comment above...